# How to let KeyCloak give a *integer* id (neither the long UUID nor the username)?

Tags: spring-security, keycloak

We are integrating KeyCloak with Spring boot (and spring security), and we want "user id" to be a integer. However, Keycloak only provides username or uuid. Thus I wonder whether there are ways to solve it?

P.S. My naive idea: Use a database table to store a mapping between uuid/username and our custom integer id. Then whenever we want to know the integer id, read the database (of course with cache).

Comment: Do you really need keycloak user id be an integer or you just want to put some additional metadata to user entity?

Comment: @solveMe I need to use an integer to identify the users. for instance, in databases, i have a column called `user_id INTEGER UNSIGNED`

Comment: Making Keycloak use int for user id will require heavy modifying Keycloak sources and building you own distribution. What about creating dedicated one-to-one table in your custom db schema for mapping user integer ids to Keycloak UUIDs? Also take a look in docs to ability to implement your custom User Storage Service Provider, maybe it is what you want if you have to deal with merging existing user storage with Keycloak.

Comment: Thanks! I may create a custom table